# How to implicate params in pagination JS script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have following JS script for load more users and filter them:

```
  <script>
    var USERS_PER_PAGE = <%= @users_per_page %>;
    var user_count = USERS_PER_PAGE;

    function checkScroll() {
      if (nearBottomOfPage()) {
        $('#loading_more_'+(user_count-USERS_PER_PAGE)).fadeTo(200, 1);
        $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "/u?start=" + user_count + "&t="<%= params[:t] %> + "&f="<%= params[:f] %>,
           dataType: "script"
         });
        user_count += USERS_PER_PAGE;
      } else {
        setTimeout(checkScroll, 250);
      }
    }
    ...
```

Also parameters can be also `empty`. For now I receive error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

[image]

How should I merge parameters for this `url` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add a route to connect this route to a controller and action

```
# routes.rb
match "/u" => "foo#bar"
```

Then you can do something like this

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '<%=j u_path(start: USERS_PER_PAGE, t: ceo, f: h) %>',
  // ...
});
```

---

**Note:** make sure you're using `<%=j ... %>` when outputting into your JavaScript with ERb. This will escape the javascript values properly.

Comment: I get error: ``undefined local variable or method `user_count' for #<#<Class:0x007fcdc79ec248>:0x007fcdbfda4960>``

Comment: You have to plugin your variables appropriately. It looks like your user count is available as `USERS_PER_PAGE` in this context.

Comment: but user_count will increase but USERS_PER_PAGE is static

Comment: and user_count is JS variable not ruby

Comment: This works on first scroll when I hardcode start parameter: ``url: <%=j u_path(start: 30, f: params[:f]) %>``